# Merging two dataframes creates new missing observations

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes with the following matching keys: year, region and province. They each have a set of variables (in this illustrative example I use x1 for df1 and x2 for df2) and both variables have several missing values on their own.

```
             df1                                             df2
year   region   province   x2  ... xn             year   region   province     x2 ... xn
2019    1          5       NA              2019    1          5         NA
2019    2          4       NA.             2019    2          4         NA.  
2019    2          4       NA.             2019    2          4         NA
2018    3          7       13.             2018    3          7         13
2018    3          7       15              2018    3          7         15
2018    3          7       17              2018    3          7         17
```

I want to merge both dataframes such that they end up like this:

```
year   region   province   x1   x2
2019    1          5        3   NA
2019    2          4       27   NA
2019    2          4       15   NA
2018    3          7       12   13
2018    3          7       NA   15
2018    3          7       NA   17
2017    4          9       NA   12
2017    4          9       19   30
2017    4          9       20   10
```

However, when doing so using `merged_df <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("year","region","province"), all.x=TRUE)`, R seems to create a lot of additional missing values on each of the variable columns (x1 and x2), which were not there before. What is happening here? I have tried sorting both using  `df1 %>% arrange(province,-year)` and `df2 %>% arrange(province,-year)`, which is enough to have matching order in both dataframes, only to find the same issue when running the `merge` command. I've tried a bunch of other stuff too, but nothing seems to work. R's output sort of looks like this:

```
year   region   province   x1   x2
2019    1          5       NA   NA
2019    2          4       NA   NA
2019    2          4       NA   NA
2018    3          7       NA   NA
2018    3          7       NA   NA
2018    3          7       NA   NA
2017    4          9       15   NA
2017    4          9       19   30
2017    4          9       20   10
```

I have done this before; in fact, one of the dataframes is an already merged dataframe in which I did not encounter this issue.

Comment: I see many duplicates on your ` by` columns, which is therefore NOT a primary key. This explains the seemingly strange results.

Comment: @Edward I’m aware of them, but it still seems strange. The data frames are intentionally structured like that; they contain several yearly observations for each province, and every province (in most cases, more than one) is part of a region. I just performed the same action on Stata and it had no trouble getting it done, which is frustrating given I don’t like that environment. And sorry about not posting a reprex or proper formatting - I’m new both to R and Stack Overflow

Comment: What's the Stata command?

Comment: @Edward merge 1:1 province region year using df2.dta; performed while df1 was loaded

Comment: @Edward so if it’s not a hassle may I ask what is the right approach?

Comment: Well, you've got duplicates. And `merge 1:1` in Stata performs a _sequential merge_. And from the Stata documentation: "Sequential merges are dangerous, because they require you to rely on sort order to know that observations belong together. Use this merge at your own risk.". If df1 and df2 have the same length, and are in the same order, then you can _probably_ do `data.frame(df1, df2)`.

Comment: @Edward I mean, I understand, as I said in the post I sorted both df’s in such a way that their orders matched, and after checking the stata output it seems like there was no mishap

Comment: @Edward I’m gonna try ‘data.frame(df1, df2)’

Comment: @Edward hmmm. This creates new variables, e.g “province.1” and “year.1”. The excessive missing values are gone, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is not clear the concept of `merge()`. I include two examples with example data. I hope you understand and it helps you.

```
#Data
set.seed(123)
DF1 <- data.frame(year=rep(c(2017,2018,2019),3),
                  region=rep(c(1,2,3),3),
                  province=round(runif(9,1,5),0),
                  x1=rnorm(9,3,1.5))
DF2 <- data.frame(year=rep(c(2016,2018,2019),3),
                  region=rep(c(1,2,3),3),
                  province=round(runif(9,1,5),0),
                  x2=rnorm(9,3,1.5))

#Merge based only in df1
Merged1 <- merge(DF1,DF2,by=intersect(names(DF1),names(DF2)),all.x=T)

Merged1
  year region province        x1       x2
1 2017      1        2 2.8365510       NA
2 2017      1        3 3.7557187       NA
3 2017      1        5 4.9208323       NA
4 2018      2        4 2.8241371       NA
5 2018      2        5 6.7925048 1.460993
6 2018      2        5 0.4090941 1.460993
7 2019      3        1 5.5352765       NA
8 2019      3        3 3.8236451 4.256681
9 2019      3        3 3.2746239 4.256681

#Merge including all elements despite no match between ids
Merged2 <- merge(DF1,DF2,by=intersect(names(DF1),names(DF2)),all = T)

Merged2
   year region province        x1       x2
1  2016      1        3        NA 4.052034
2  2016      1        4        NA 2.062441
3  2016      1        5        NA 2.673038
4  2017      1        2 2.8365510       NA
5  2017      1        3 3.7557187       NA
6  2017      1        5 4.9208323       NA
7  2018      2        1        NA 0.469960
8  2018      2        2        NA 2.290813
9  2018      2        4 2.8241371       NA
10 2018      2        5 6.7925048 1.460993
11 2018      2        5 0.4090941 1.460993
12 2019      3        1 5.5352765       NA
13 2019      3        2        NA 1.398264
14 2019      3        3 3.8236451 4.256681
15 2019      3        3 3.2746239 4.256681
16 2019      3        4        NA 1.906663
```

Comment: Wow, that worked seamlessly! Would you care to develop and explain why `Merged1 <- merge(DF1,DF2,by=intersect(names(DF1),names(DF2)),all.x=T)` worked, but `merged_df <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("year","region","province"), all.x=TRUE)` messed up the output?

Comment: @Kamyen Hi. Maybe due to the names of each dataframe. You have to check that all names are equal in order to define as keys in the `by` argument of merge. `names(DF1)` gives you that output. Sometimes names have spaces or can be of different types as `numeric` or factor. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, so if it’s the case that the column names mismatch, then if I understand correctly the command you said would just merge regardless of whether the key matches?

Comment: @Kamyen `intersect()` will find common names between all dataframes so that merge can be done. You can play around the dummy datasets changing names to have a better understanding :)

Comment: @Kamyen You are welcome. If you feel this answer was useful you can just accept it :)

Comment: @Kamyen. You should check carefully that this answer gives the same as your Stata command.

Comment: @Edward I did, using ```all.equal(df1, df2)```. R returned the following: 
```> all.equal(Rmerg,dataMerge)
[1] "Names: 4 string mismatches"                                                    
[2] "Attributes: < Component “row.names”: Modes: character, numeric >"              
[3] "Attributes: < Component “row.names”: target is character, current is numeric >"
[4] "Component 6: Mean relative difference: 2.7709e-08"  ```

What does this mean? I also did a manual check, comparing several random rows of both sets, and they seem to match (the sets are small, around 1000 rows each)